# Unable to Force SSL/https using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

i'm using open-school php on my host and i'm trying to force ssl on my website but when i add this code

```
     RewriteEngine On 
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but then i'm unable to access my website as the browser says too many loops or redirects

**The page isn't redirecting properly**

**Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.**

here is the orignal htacess file 
please help

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On


#Admin
Rewriterule ^admin$ index.php?r=Cms/admin/home
#Install
Rewriterule ^install$ install.php?r=Install/default

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `%{SERVER_PORT}` line, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

This is a complete `.htaccess` file that I use to force any website to SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```